# Chrome app for Windows in the background, using hooks

Tags: windows, hook, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I want to write an application for Windows that will work in the background and track some hooks, but as yet are not familiar with this development environment would like to know whether it is possible implementation of these tasks into the chrome app. Why chrome app? -Because, the application will interact with the application for android, it's simply easier to develop ...

So my questions are:
1. Chrome app in the background?
2. Chrome app and windows hooks?

If possible please bring a small example, or a manual on the implementation of the goals ...

P.S. Thank you very much for your participation and apologies for mistakes and awkwardness of speech (English is not my native language)!

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure you will be unable to use global keyboard hooks in a chrome app. It would allow key loggers and other "bad thing"...

You can read this for more information :https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chromium-extensions/yPGeRn9y7Dc

Comment: What makes you interpret the question as "keyboard hooks"?